# Get Latitude and Longitude using only internet

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, locationmanager

```
//        GET LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE BY INTERNET
        LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean netEnabled = lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (netEnabled) {
            lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            Location location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null)
            {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
```

I am trying to get lat and long using only the internet. The code above works only if I open the location. what did I have to change?

Comment: do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` in your manifest?

Comment: of course I have it. and also Fine.Location